Navigating to swiftui view from push notification
I have a multiple root navigationView in swiftui view, I am setting the root based on a state variable, the issue is that when I am navigating to a screen from a push notification click and then click back, it returns me to the root view not the one was openned before the click of the push notification.
for example:
I am navigating A -> B -> C
then open D screen from the push notification, click back, it returns me to A not to C
I am navigating to the push details screen based on a state variable in the content view screen.
Main App code:
@main
struct Push_Notification_POCApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor private var appDelegate: AppDelegate
    @StateObject var notificationManager = NotificationManager()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onAppear{
                    appDelegate.app = self
                    Task{
                        await notificationManager.request()
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

ContentView Code:
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var navigateTpPushNotificationPage = false
    
    @State var rootPage = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                switch rootPage {
                case 0:
                    ScreenA()
                case 1:
                    ScreenB()
                case 2:
                    ScreenC()
                default:
                    ScreenA()
                }
                
                NavigationLink(destination: ScreenFromPuah(), isActive: $navigateTpPushNotificationPage, label: {
                    EmptyView()
                })
                .hidden()
            }
            .padding()
            .onAppear {
                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name("NavigateToScreen"), object: nil, queue: .main) { notification in
                    navigateTpPushNotificationPage = true
                    
                }
            }
            
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        
    }
}



struct ScreenA: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: ScreenB()) {
            Text("Open Screen B")
        }
    }
}

struct ScreenB: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: ScreenC()) {
            Text("Open Screen C")
        }
    }
}

struct ScreenC: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Open Screen C")
    }
}

struct ScreenFromPuah: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Opened From Push")
    }
}

AppDelegate code:
import Foundation
import UIKit

//MARK: AppDelegate
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, ObservableObject {
    var app: Push_Notification_POCApp?
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        
        return true
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let stringifiedToken = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
        print("stringifiedToken:", stringifiedToken)
    }
}

extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("NavigateToScreen"), object: "open page c")
        completionHandler()
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification) async -> UNNotificationPresentationOptions {
        return [.badge, .banner, .list, .sound]
    }
}

So how to navigate from push notification without losing the current navigation stack ?

Note, NavigationView is deprecated you should use NavigationStack.
Try using NavigationStack with NavigationStack(path: $path) and navigationDestination(...).

The project has a minimum deploy target of ios 14, NavigationStack can't be used in ios 14. @workingdogsupportUkraine
